# IB - add UIView to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I like to accomplish an UIToolbar below an UITableView and I wanted to use the UITableViewController because it sets up the data source and delegate and other stuff on its own.

I don't need an UINavigationController as has been proposed in similar topics due to only having 1 view currently and my data is without a hierarchy.

I didn't manage to drag and drop an UIView or UIToolbar to my UITableViewController at any place (scene design area or view hierarchy) in Interface Builder of XCode 4.2.

Thus my question: How to add an UIView to an UITableViewController in Interface Builder?

I did manage to achieve the look I intend to accomplish using an UIViewController with an UITableView and an UIToolbar contained in its UIView.

Would using an UIViewController with an UITableView be much more involved than relying on the UITableViewController?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is your real question

> Would using an UIViewController with an UITableView be much more
>   involved than relying on the UITableViewController?

The answer is no, its not much more work. Just add this to the viewcontrollers' .h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Then in the .h add the datasource and delegate functions( you could just copy and paste the functions your'e currently using in your TableViewController)

NOTE: From Xcode 4.5.1: "Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances."

Comment: I have a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460559/cocoa-uitableview-not-scrolling-when-not-assigned-to-parents-uiviewcontroller). While I signed your answer as helpful I wait with signing it "accepted" in case someone answers the first question. Thank you again.

Comment: Why was the edit done to this when the "NOTE" should have just been added as a comment? That is not what edit is for.

Comment: I may be stating the obvious, but you also need to call setDataSource and setDelegate on the table view reference, and pass a reference to the UIViewController in those methods.