# UITableView not scrolling when not assigned to parents UIViewController view property

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, scroll

I have put an UITableView inside a UIViewController and have copied code from UITableViewController over to my UIViewController to have it fulfill "Table data protocols" with UITableViewControllers default implementation and am following http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10s chapter "Creating a Table View Programmatically" (with using ViewDidLoad instead of LoadView as I use IB and have a nib, I created an outlet for the UITableView named tableView).

Now in above links chapter the UITableView is assigned to self.view which is the UIView property of the UIViewController. Then scrolling the UITableView is working but the UITableView fills the entire screen hiding other view content such as an UIToolbar - probably as it is the sole content after being assigned to the view property.

If I omit the assignment, the other view content is in place an everything is sized properly, however the UITableView doesn't scroll.

How do I achieve scrolling of the UITableView inside an UIViewController with the UIVC having static content (such as a toolbar)?

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];
    //self.view = tableView;
}
```

Comment: You need a clear paragraph between text and code for the markup to kick in. I changed this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have other content in the view controller that you are adding in interface builder then this will be part of the UIViewController's .view property - when you assign the table view to this, you are removing all that content.

If your table view is appearing normally but is not scrolling (how about selection? Does that work?) you may have disabled user interaction on it.

You have mentioned in comments that there is nothing but empty cells in your table view - I think this is the cause of your problem. I have just created a sample project where I have added in a table view as a subview of the view controller's view, and scrolling is fine - this is with me populating 100 dummy rows in there. If I don't return anything for the datasource and delegate methods, then the table view does not scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the markup correction. User interaction is enabled. The only difference is the last line in the code above: self.view=tableView. There isn't anything to select yet beyond empty cells.

Comment: Ok then, I will try a sample project here to see if I can reproduce - this won't be for a while though as its the end of the day here.

Comment: Did you check the user interaction on the table view or the global view? (it the table view has user interaction enabled but not the global one, everything would make sense)

Comment: the global view has ui enabled. The table view resides in the global view and ib doesn't publish an ui checkbox in its attributes inspector. I tried tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; programmatically. It didn't help. Thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: I have tried my sample project - I think your problem is that you have no data for the table view yet. See updated answer.

Comment: Indeed. Returning some rows with 1 section (the default was 0 each) lets the table scroll. Thank you!